# IE and absolute positioning divs

Tags: css, internet-explorer, position, absolute

This problem is only in IE.  Consider the following HTML:

```
 <html>
 <body>
 <div style='position:absolute;left:1em;right:1em;top:1em;bottom:1em;overflow:auto;>
 Put more than a full screen of text in here.  It *should* create a scroll inside the div.
 In IE, it stretches the div out vertically.
 <div>
 <body>
 <html>
```

If you put a ton of text in the div, IE will stretch the div out beyond the declared "bottom".  I know what it is doing.  It considers the bottom of the page to be the bottom of the page after all of the text has been rendered.  I want bottom to be the bottom of the visible window.  So, I want to have a div that is centered inside the window.  Is there some retarded hack to make IE comprehend the basic concept of CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [conflicting absolute positions](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/conflictingabsolutepositions/) don't forget the fix for IE6 under the 'Creating the exception for IE5 and IE6' header in that article.

Answer (score 0):

```
body: 100%;

div#id height: 100%;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try using a conditional comment to add `overflow:auto;` for IE only.